# How to derive the equations of motion of finite temperature Green function?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, fermions, greens-functions, many-body

I'm having a trouble deriving the equation of motion of a Green function. My understanding of the derivation is the following.

Given a set of fermionic creation annihilation operators
$$\{a_\alpha (\vec{r}),a^\dagger_\beta (\vec{r}')\} = \delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')\delta_{\alpha \beta} ,~~\{a_\alpha (\vec{r}),a_\beta (\vec{r}')\} = \{a^\dagger_\alpha (\vec{r}),a^\dagger_\beta (\vec{r}')\} =0 .$$
where $\alpha = \uparrow,\downarrow$. The Hamiltonian is
$$H = \sum_\alpha\int d^3 r ~ a^\dagger_\alpha (\vec{r}) \left(\frac{\nabla_r^2}{2m}-\mu\right)a_\alpha (\vec{r}) + \frac{1}{2}  \sum_{\alpha,\beta}\int d^3 r d^3 r' ~ V(|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|)a^\dagger_\alpha (\vec{r})a^\dagger_\beta (\vec{r}')a_\beta (\vec{r}')a_\alpha (\vec{r})$$

The time evolution of a fermionic annheliation operator is
$a_\alpha(\vec{r},\tau) = e^{\tau H}a_\alpha(\vec{r}) e^{-\tau H}.$
Taking a derivative with $\tau$ gives
$$\frac{\partial a_\alpha(\vec{r},\tau)}{\partial \tau} = e^{\tau H}[H,a_\alpha(\vec{r})]e^{-\tau H} =  e^{\tau H}\{H,a_\alpha(\vec{r})\}e^{-\tau H} -2e^{\tau H}a_\alpha (\vec{r})H e^{-\tau H} $$
Let us denote $\{H,a_\alpha(\vec{r})\} = K$ and define $e^{\tau H}Ke^{-\tau H}\equiv K(\tau)$, then we have $\frac{\partial a_\alpha(\vec{r},\tau)}{\partial \tau} =K(\tau)-2 a_\alpha (\vec{r},\tau) H. $
Taking a $\tau$ derivative of a Green function $G \equiv -<T_\tau a_\alpha (\vec{r},\tau)a^\dagger_\beta (\vec{r}',\tau')>
$ gives
$$- \frac{\partial G}{\partial \tau}  = \delta(\tau-\tau')\left<\{a_\alpha (\vec{r},\tau),a^\dagger_\beta (\vec{r}',\tau')\}\right>+ \left<T_\tau \frac{\partial a_\alpha (\vec{r},\tau)}{\partial \tau}a^\dagger_\beta (\vec{r}',\tau')\right>$$
where $\delta(x)=\partial_x\theta (x) = - \partial_x \theta (-x)$ was used.

Inserting $\frac{\partial a_\alpha(\vec{r},\tau)}{\partial \tau} =K(\tau)-2 a_\alpha (\vec{r},\tau) H$ gives the equations of motion of the Green function. However, if I compare my result with equation from some text book (for example section 14.2 of [https://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Mechanics-Superconductivity-Graduate-Physics/dp/4431554041](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/4431554041)) one should have
$$\frac{\partial a_\alpha(\vec{r},\tau)}{\partial \tau} =K(\tau)
$$
instead of
$$\frac{\partial a_\alpha(\vec{r},\tau)}{\partial \tau} =K(\tau)-2 a_\alpha (\vec{r},\tau) H
$$
**Question**: How come the last term "$a_\alpha (\vec{r},\tau) H$" in the above equation is missing from the derivation of the equations of motion?

Comment: Inytroducing the anticommutator is misleading. It is straightforward (although tedious, like many things in physics) to commute the annihilation operator with the Hamiltonian and the equations will readily come out. A good exercise is to start with calculating commutators $[a_\alpha, a_\beta^\dagger a_\gamma]$ and  $[a_\alpha, a_\beta^\dagger a_\gamma^\dagger a_{\gamma'}a_{\beta'}]$, using the *anticommutation* relations for the creation/annihilation operators.

Comment: @RogerVadim Thank you, I completely misused the expansion of the anti-commutator (I was misusing {AB,C}=A{B,C}+{A,C}B) which is obviously wrong.